# Miktex cannot install pdflscape on fly even though it has it in packages

Tags: packages, miktex

I've reinstalled windows and now trying to compile the same .tex document that was working perfectly before (TexStudio + MikTex). Unfortunately, I always end up with an error that seems to be related to a missing package.

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
```

The error is:

> File `pdflscape.sty' not found. \usepackage

However, if I search for pdflscape in MikTex packages I see it. The database is refreshed, and packages are updated (in user mode).
[image]

Any idea what might cause the error? And how to solve it **without manual package installation** via the console.

P.S. If I manually install pdflscape via MikTex console, I'll get more errors that all seem to be related to missing packages. I suspect all those errors have the same root, so I'd like to focus on solving this issue without manual package installation.

Comment: does miktex say that it is installed? Do you have pdflscape.sty somewhere?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can locate the package in MikTex console. So it seems that it's aware of the package's existence. However, it is not installed. Even though TexStudio attempted to request it

Comment: Well then install if with the miktex console.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer tried it already but run into more weird errors with tikz-uml package: "Extra \or. \end{umlcallself}", which I cannot resolve (latest .sty is in the project, all listed in the tikz-uml doc packages are installed, but nothing helps).  My only explanation is that something is wrong with the FNDB, so it cannot find all dependencies and hence cannot build tikz-uml. I hope that if can solve pdflscape error without manual installation, then tkiz-uml will work too.

Comment: pdflscape has nothing to do with tikz. If pdflscape is not there you have to install it with the miktex console. LaTeX can not create it out of thin air. Once it is installed you can handle the next error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer MikTex is supposed to install all packages that TexStudio needs for making the document (or building included .sty). It should not be a manual process. For some reason, all other packages (amssymb, etc) were successfully installed on the fly, only pdflscape failed. I tried to solve tkiz-uml error, but could not. My only idea at this point is to find a way to fix pdflscape issue without manual installation because I think the failure is related to not finding packages rather than something with tikz

Comment: on-the-fly can fail. You need pdflscape so install it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I install it manually, then xelatex outputs  "Extra \or. \end{umlcallself}" related to tkiz-uml. Removing all diagrams will result in a good .pdf file. As for the diagram, it doesn't matter if it's mine or a test example from tikz-uml doc - it will give the error. I cannot solve this problem. It's definitely windows-related as on ubuntu everything works like a charm. I suspect some internal dependency of tikz-uml is not installed, but I don't know which.

Comment: sure but that is the *next* error. Ask a new question with a small complete example and the log-file about that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Currently I want to solve the 1st error - how to make MikTex install pdflscape without me manually installing it from the console. I want to know why exactly it fails.

Comment: well it looks odd that the size is shown as 0 bytes. And the date looks wrong too. Try to update the package database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the pdflscape packaging https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/303. But the last update repaired that.

You should now see this in the package list:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it works! The package was installed on the fly